# Java Search Pattern RegularExpression Style

Tags: java, regex, search

My Question is the following:

**Is there a Pattern-Builder in Java which can be feeded with input and builds a search/regex pattern for it?**

**The example:**

**What i have:**
Load the List of names.
Start reading the file, and check each line with the full List of Names. (This creates a Cartesian product, but I don't want that).

**What i want to achieve:**
Load List of Names which should be considered for the regular expressions
Create Pattern and load all the names into the pattern.
Read the first file and check it with the pattern.

So you can see that I would like to reduce the Cartesian product down to an O[n] sequence to save performance.

Conditions:
      The Regular Expression pattern should be loaded from a list, so it will be dynamic.
The input can be anything, the output should be an alert in case any of the names matches.

If you think I have not provided enough please ask, ill be glad to provide more information wherever I can.

Comment: What is wrong with `name1|name2|name3|...|nameN` pattern? Unless names have metacharacters, you don't need to do anything special about it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Lets imagine we have 200 000 names, than I would need to run the regexp about 200 000 times per line.

Comment: Adding 200000 items to a regexp pattern does not make a list of 200000 items that regexp searches. The compile method makes your pattern into a finite state machine, letting you search for any one of the names from the list relatively quickly. The compilation process may take some time, though.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight There is another point, i want the regexp to be dynamic, i get the list from a file, so it will not be able to compile it into the program, it has to happen at runtime

Comment: @OliverStutz regexp are not compiled at compile time but at runtime

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul thanks for the info, do you know the limitations of pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately dasblinkenlight has put in the answer in the comments,

The results of compiling such a huge pattern is alright, i tried it with a 4.5 MB pattern. I hope there is no limitation to that.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a Set with names. This will guarant you to have distinct list of name with O(1) access time. Then you can check that name from line in the file exists in that set.

But this might not be perfect solution. To gain more help you should provide the file preview and example input and output.

Comment: i dont have an example input and output, the aim is to have some kind of regexp pattern which contains up to 1 mio records which i can use like a regexp syntax to scan each line and if the line would contain a name listed it should abort. Its like an alerting mechanism if the file contains any of the names in a list